# How do I exit MELPA in emacs?

Tags: emacs, ide, editor, package-managers, melpa

I'm trying to learn Emacs, and I've installed MELPA as a package manager.  The only problem is that the only way I know how to exit MELPA is by quitting Emacs entirely.  I'm sure there's a better way to do this.  What is it?

Comment: I don't understand: as far  as I know, MELPA is not a package manager but one of the ELPA package archives (typically accessed with the package manager that comes bundled with Emacs since 24.1).  So I don't know what you mean by "install MELPA", and I have no idea what "exit MELPA" might mean either.

Comment: I probably mean setup.  I'm really asking how I get out of the screen I'm on after I type M-x package-list

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Killing buffers with `C-x k RET` is generally good advice, but it is much easier to quit the `package-list-packages` screen by simply pressing `q`.

This also works to exit `dired` buffers, `magit`, and many other types of buffers that aren't text-oriented.

Answer (score 0):

- `C-x C-f` open file
- `C-x C-b` open buffer list
- `C-x b` open buffer
- `M-x` execute command

C - ctrl and M - alt

Also take a tour [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/tour/)